# How to use data-theme in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to add Dark Mode to my website, which is built in React, that I've created, and while I don't want to create an actual Dark Mode, I want to add lazy dark mode using `filter: invert(1)` in CSS.

The issue came mainly when trying to communicate between the TSX file and CSS file to check which mode do I want to show, and trying to use `data-theme` doesn't seem to work for me.

My App.tsx is as follows:

```js
function App() {
  const defaultDark = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches;
  const [theme, setTheme] = useLocalStorage('theme', defaultDark ? 'dark' : 'light');
  
  const toggleTheme = () => {
    setTheme(theme === 'light' ? 'dark' : 'light');
    console.log(theme);
  }

  return (
    <div className="outer-container" id="outer-container" data-theme={theme}>
      <Sidebar />
      <button onClick={toggleTheme}>
        Click here to switch to {theme === 'light' ? 'dark' : 'light'} mode
      </button>
      <div className='page'>
      <Outlet />
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

(I do have certain imports but all the components are different file)
My App.css is as follows:

```css
.outer-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 85vh;
}

.page {
  flex: 1;
}

footer {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 1rem;
}

footer .row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

hr {
  height: 0px;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

p#p1 {
  position: absolute;
    width: 20vw;
    height: 34px;
    left: 19px;

    font-family: 'PT Serif';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 95.52%;

    /* or 12px */

    color: #000000;
}

p#p2 {
  position: absolute;
    width: 20vw;
    height: 34px;
    left: calc(50vw - 10vw);

    font-family: 'PT Serif';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 95.52%;

    /* or 12px */

    color: #000000;
}

p#p3 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 34px;
  left: calc(100vw - 20vw);

  font-family: 'PT Serif';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 95.52%;

  color: #000000;
}

div.main {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 34px;
  top: 5vw;
  left: calc(100vw - 20vw);
}

a.social {
  margin: 0 1rem;
  transition: transform 250ms;
  display: inline-block;
  align-items: center;
}

a.social:hover {
  transform: translateY(-2px);
}

a.youtube, a.youtube:hover {
  color: #eb3223;
}

a.github, a.github:hover {
  color: #24292e;
}

a.discord, a.discord:hover {
  color: #7289da;
}

html[data-theme='dark'] {
  filter: invert(1) hue-rotate(180deg);
}
```

(I'm not sure if it matters and hence I've shown the whole thing, but the important thing is the last one; also I do have some CSS for internal components)

However, even so, when I click on the button, nothing changes, even though the value of the theme changes. How would I fix this?

Thank you :)